# How to access pages with basic authentication (Apify SDK)

Tags: authentication, puppeteer, apify

In the puppeteer documentation i found that i could use
`await page.authenticate({ username: 'test', password: 'test' });`
To access pages with basic authentication.

But it seems that the [handlePageFunction](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/cheerio-crawler-options#handlepagefunction) has already done the request.

So how could i do that?

```
Apify.main(async () => {

const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue(`PC_${settings.project}_${time}`);
await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: settings.baseUrl });

const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
    requestQueue,
    launchPuppeteerOptions: {
        headless: settings.headless,
        // slowMo: 500,
    },
    maxRequestsPerCrawl: settings.maxurls,
    maxConcurrency: settings.maxcrawlers,
    handlePageFunction: async ({ request, response, page }) => {
        await page.authenticate({ username: 'test', password: 'test' });
        await page.waitFor(settings.waitForPageload);

        const requestUrl = request.url
        const loadUrl = request.loadedUrl
        let isRedirected = false

        if (requestUrl !== loadUrl) {
            isRedirected = { from: requestUrl, to: loadUrl }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the page before it is opened with [`gotoFunction`](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/puppeteer-crawler-options#gotofunction).

If you would need to login to a website, you can check this small [login example](https://help.apify.com/en/articles/1640711-how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-puppeteer)

```
const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
    gotoFunction: async ({ page, request }) => {
        await page.authenticate({ username: 'test', password: 'test' });
        return page.goto(request.url, { timeout: 120000 });
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - i think the `gotoFunction` is that what im looking for. Do you have any example for that? I don't know where and how i could add `page.authenticate`

Comment: Add this as a field to PuppeteerCrawler

: gotoFunction: async ({ page, request }) => {
    await page.authenticate() // add your creds
    return page.goto(request.url, { timeout: 120000 })
}